# laravel 5.1 using middleware to Access incoming and outgoing request

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

i am trying to measure the data size of all incoming and out going request using a middleware in laravel. i am building an api.
This will help me know the internet data my application is using in terms of uploads and downloads.
the problem is that i cannot get access to data being sent from my server to the client or browser and i think it is because i am new to laravel.
 i just want to measure the json data being sent from my server to the client and all inputs received from the client.
 When i log the log the request, i don't get the data i want. how to get the size of the data into kilobytes will also be helpful.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Log;


class MeasureDataSizeMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
// measure the size
    //store the data into a database of incoming and outgoing request.
     //Log::info('app.requests', ['request' => $request, 'response' => new Response($response)]);

       }
    }
```

Comment: I cant understand what not working? why in event you can measure but in middleware you cant? give us some php code, errors, data just saying its not working is not helping

Comment: @AmirBar     i have not being able to achieve the result using an event. i just think since it will be applied to every request, an event wouldn't be necessary but rather a middleware. Thanks for having the time to read this.

Comment: Why do you need to measure the amount of data **coming in**? At the point where you measure that, the memory has already been allocated. This size is always present in HTTP header called `Content-Length`. The best scenario is that you modify your http server (nginx hopefully, it excels at things like this) and you set the appropriate metrics there (you can deny requests that are larger than some value so they never reach your app).

Comment: @Mjh it is for measuring the internet usage that is uploads and downloads. it has nothing to do with any complex stuff. i am building the app for a client and would want the client to know the internet usage of the application in making and receiving request.

Comment: Well, PHP application is the wrong place for this. But - on topic: to fix the issue you're having - did you register the middleware you created? It doesn't appear as you have, which is why it's not getting called.

Comment: @Mjh it is working cos i have registered but don't know how to access the data for example if in my controller i return a json data to the client, i want to have access to it using the middleware and measure the size.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in your middleware, that stores the data you need in the database, further in the controller using Eloquent you can query what you want. I hope this helps you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).